# Example of using

Tags: coffeescript, jira

I want to search for JIRA Server users using [searchUsers](https://github.com/jira-node/node-jira-client/blob/master/src/jira.js#L488) from  https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-client
Can you provide a working example?

Mine never returns anything (fyi, addNewissue function worked fine)

```
jira.searchUsers("jane.doe").then((user) ->
  console.log(user.length)
).catch (err) ->
  console.error err
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, the jira client is written in ES6, which I'm not that familiar with, but I think that the `searchUsers` function actually expects an object argument, not a list.

```
 searchUsers({ username, startAt, maxResults, includeActive, includeInactive }) { ... }
```

The `{username, startAt...}` is a destructuring assignment which pulls key names from a single passed object and turns them into variables. As per the function's comments, you should pass an options object.
Try it like this:

```
jira.searchUsers({username: "jane.doe"}).then((user) ->
  console.log(user.length)
).catch (err) ->
  console.error err
```

Comment: yes it's obvious now that you explained it ! thank you